# SQL: Allow NULL on two columns but not both

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that is simply a lookup with two columns.

```
spiceId - INT
spiceDes - VARCHAR(100)
```

Now, I have the columns set as allow NULL for both columns, but I would like to add a constraint where it should be that only one column could be NULL for any record. That is spiceID and spiceDes could not, both be NULL.

How can I add this constraint?

Comment: Are both columns allowed to be non-NULL? I.e. is this "at least one column must not be `NULL`" or "exactly one column must not be `NULL`"?

Comment: Neither. They both can be NOT NULL, but they both cannot be NULL. The only combinations allowed are NULL, NOT NULL **or** NOT NULL, NULL **or** NOT NULL, NOT NULL. Never it can be NULL, NULL.

Comment: How is that neither? It sounds exactly like "at least one column must not be `NULL`".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes you are correct. I was thinking you meant one column must be NULL. Sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 11):

[Use `Alter table` to add a `check constraint` on your table:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190377.aspx#TsqlProcedure)

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_nulltest
CHECK (spiceId IS NOT NULL OR spiceDes IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about [CHECK Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx)?

```
ADD CONSTRAINT chkIsNotNull CHECK (spiceId is not null or spiceDes is not null);
```